# Escape velocity of Milky Way galaxy

Tags: galaxy

I'm wondering that what would be the **escape velocity** of our Galaxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500+ kps.  There's a pretty good answer over at https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/escape-velocity-for-our-galaxy, but the question appears to fit here as well.

For a mass all located inside a circular orbit, escape velocity is a simple function of orbital velocity, but that ignores most of the mass outside that circular orbit (all of it if its distribution is spherically symmetric).  The Milky Way has a *lot* of mass outside the Sun's orbit, though.